# Getting an Error 403 when my tries to run specific command

Tags: python, discord, bots

I am trying to add a custom command to my python-coded discord bot but it gives me the error mentioned in the title of my post. I have updated the bot's OAuth2 link to include admin permissions and made the sure the bot's role is highest in the roles list.

Here is my command code:
@bot.command(name="winter_contingency")
async def winter_contingency(ctx):
# Check if the user has the "Admin" role
def is_admin(member):
admin_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Admin")
return admin_role in member.roles

```
if not is_admin(ctx.author):
    await ctx.send("Scquire, thou hast no right to command me!")
    return

try:
    # Remove roles from all members except admins
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        if not is_admin(member):
            await member.remove_roles(*member.roles[1:])

    # Check if the "WINTER CONTINGENCY" role already exists
    winter_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="WINTER CONTINGENCY")
    if not winter_role:
        # Create the role if it doesn't exist
        winter_role = await ctx.guild.create_role(name="WINTER CONTINGENCY")

    # Assign the "WINTER CONTINGENCY" role to all members
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        if not is_admin(member):
            await member.add_roles(winter_role)

    # Find the announcements channel
    announcements_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name='announcements',
                                              type=discord.ChannelType.text)

    # Check if announcements channel exists
    if announcements_channel:
        await announcements_channel.send("WINTER CONTINGENCY declared. Please refer to the #winter-contingency channel for more information.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Announcements channel not found.")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

I was expecting the command to function. It should have removed all members roles and replace it with the "WINTER CONTINGENCY" role and also it should have sent a message in the #announcements channel of the discord server.